# Delay or display animated photo timer before capturing photo using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer, webcam, animated-gif

I have created various JavaScript  functions to capture photo from the browser. Using the JavaScript functions i can successfully launch camera, capture photos and preview it and then able to upload the photos.

I am thinking to integrate photo timer function. Here, once i click on the take photo button it will wait for 3 seconds (for example) and will display an animated timer (i am thinking to load a an Animated gif file) that will countdown 3 to 1. Once the countdown is finished i want to call the photo capturing function.

But i could not able to integrate this logic in my photo capturing functionality!

**My sample code is :**

```
var cameraEnabled = false;
var timer = null;

$('#takeButton').click(function(){

    if(timer != null)
    {
      clearTimeout(timer); 
      timer = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!cameraEnabled){
            return false;
        }
        timer = window.setTimeout(webcam.show_image(), 3000);
        webcam.freeze();
        togglePane();
        return false;
    }

});
```

**My show_image function is:**

```
 show_image:function()
 {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "countdowntimer.gif";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
 },
```

Could anyone please help me on this issue?

Advance thanks for your responses.

Comment: This might not be your problem but `setTimeout` takes milliseconds as the second parameter. So currently its waiting 30 seconds call `webcam.show_image`. Also `webcam.show_image()` shouldn't have the parenthesis, i believe it is currently calling it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timer = window.setTimeout(webcam.show_image(), 30000);
```

When you do this, you actually call webcam.show_image and then pass result of function to setTimeout. To pass pointer to function you should do

```
timer = window.setTimeout(webcam.show_image, 30000);
```

Additionally, I don't think it's a good idea to use animated gif for text countdown, you can just manipulate innerHTML in some DIV.
Finally, 30000 ms is 30 secs, not 3.

Comment: Hi Tommi..thanks i like the code..but could you tell me how can i integrate the shoot function without using the alert?? My shoot function is webcam.freeze(); After shooting i am toggling the pane and return false..for example: togglePane(); return false;

Comment: Then just remove alert and paste webcam.freeze(); togglePane(); instead

Comment: Its a really very good help for me..thanks Tommi.. the timer logic is coming up.. but still i am having different issues which i am going to fix. if i can't fix, i will post the rest of the codes again.

Comment: Tommi..there is one bug in your code logic though i am not sure! after displaying the alert and closing the alert message when i again click on the button it starts to count (-). How it can be fixed? I think i have to write a function to reload the UI?

Comment: Sure, it was a proof-of-concept and I thoght you'll investigate code and implement it for yourself. Anyway, you should reinitialize counter variable (timeto = 3) when user clicks on button. For example, like this http://jsfiddle.net/s5gUh/2/